# How to fix broken up text with python docx to get free text for Ebooks?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to edit a free Ebook I found online into easily readable text for Kindle, with headers and full paragraphs.

I'm very new to Python and coding in general so I don't really have any progress.

Each line is separated by a break with Enter, so each line is considered a separate Paragraph by python.

Basically what needs to be done is delete the space and breaks between the lines so the text doesn't break when converted into MOBI or EPUB.

The text looks like this:

Unformatted:
[image]

And should look like this:

Formatted:
[image]

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What have you done so far in python? Please provide code and result or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the docx library that is not installed by default, you can use pip or conda:

```
pip install python-docx
conda install python-docx --channel conda-forge
```

After install:

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document(r'path\to\file\pride_and_prejudice.docx')
all_text=[]
all_text_str=''

for para in doc.paragraphs:
    all_text.append(para.text)

all_text_str=all_text_str.join(all_text)

clean_text=all_text_str.replace('\n', '')   # Remove linebreaks
clean_text=clean_text.replace('  ', '')    # Remove even number of spaces (e.g. This usually eliminates non-spaces nicely, but you can tweak accordingly.

document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph(clean_text)
document.save(r'path\to\file\pride_and_prejudice_clean.docx')
```

Comment: Thanks! So what that did was make everything clean text, no paragraph breaks or anything. I'll try to tweak it a bit.

How did you learn to use this module by the way? I've been looking for a guide but couldn't find one.

Comment: Sure :) Here is the documentation with plenty of helper scripts under the User Guide [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)   I really only stumbled accross it before, while learning to interact with most document formats in python :). Regarding the paragraphs, you might want to check `document.add_page_break()` or depending on the structure of the book(s) you may not want to replace them at all. Feel free to upvote, or if you need more help you can post some text of the book including a typical paraghraph you would want to save in the formatting.